# When I install and run Tauri on Mac OS Monterey I get immediate error

Tags: node.js, npm, rust, tauri

I installed it via:

```
npm create tauri-app
```

I chose a vanilla JavaScript environment to code it.

I run:

```
  cd app
  npm install
  npm run tauri dev
```

The result is this error:

```
> app@0.0.0 tauri
> tauri dev

thread '<unnamed>' panicked at 'called `Result::unwrap()` on an `Err` value: Os { code: 2, kind: NotFound, message: "No such file or directory" }', src/interface/rust.rs:762:69
note: run with `RUST_BACKTRACE=1` environment variable to display a backtrace
```

I am on Mac OS Monterey.

I searched the error online and it seems it might have something to do with
my systems time configuration but I am unsure.

Comment: Maybe you can't just run this thing out of the box, it appears to be missing some file. Have you confirmed with the documentation you're running it correctly? Is there a setup procedure that has to come first?

Comment: It appears to be coming from the tauri cli and not the default app. Maybe try running with the cargo tauri cli like so: `cargo tauri dev`. Install with `cargo install tauri-cli`

Comment: This error should mean that you didn't install Rust, or the cli can't find it. Make sure to follow https://tauri.app/v1/guides/getting-started/prerequisites#setting-up-macos and restart your terminal (or whole system) afterwards.

Comment: Yes, I didn't install rust. I assumed it was part of the package. I'll edit the query

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to install Rust before Tauri. Installing Tauri does not include Rust.

Installation instructions, according to [Rust's documentation](https://www.rust-lang.org/tools/install):

`curl --proto '=https' --tlsv1.2 -sSf https://sh.rustup.rs | sh`

Comment: this installs just rust, the anwer is: https://stackoverflow.com/a/75580172/18185259 down below

Answer (score 5):

The answer is

```
cargo install tauri-cli
```

this install the `tauri` command, and cli to be able to execute the `tauri` app.

this installs just rust

```
curl --proto '=https' --tlsv1.2 -sSf https://sh.rustup.rs | sh
```

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the platform, there are some steps to take to fix that which is only required for the first time you are creating Tauri app

**For MacOs**
Step 1: Install CLang and macOS Development Dependencies using

```
xcode-select --install
```

Step 2: Install Rust using

```
curl --proto '=https' --tlsv1.2 https://sh.rustup.rs -sSf | sh
```

Check out official docs for more at https://tauri.app/v1/guides/getting-started/prerequisites

Answer (score 0):

yarn add -D @tauri-apps/cli && yarn install